# Why my jquery script animate doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, browser-support

Here is simple backround position animate. Why IE 8 on mouse away don't animate it ? 
Opera and Firefox don't show any action and only Chrome do it well.
How to make it work at all lates version browsers ?

```
$(function(){
$(".call_order").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPositionX: "-300"
    }, 100);
} , function() { 
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPositionX: "0"
    }, 100);
});
```

});

[Here is a sample](http://selen-dar.ru/alexqem/Buhuchet/index2.html)

Comment: Firefox doesn't recognize `background-position-x`, only the combined `background-position: xvalue yvalue`. Possibly the other browsers are the same.

Comment: Why don't you use css [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) and css [transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) instead of using jquery?

Comment: Alexander, if the answer under was ok, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox and Opera do not support `backgroundPositionX` and `backgroundPositionY` (bec. it is not in the corresponding specifications.) and [IE8 seems to be buggy](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position#compatibilitysection) even with `background-position`.

**Browser Support** for `backgroundPositionX` and `backgroundPositionY`:

```
    Browser       Version
    ----------------------------
    Opera         Not Supported  
    Firefox       Not Supported  
    Safari        3+  
    IE            4+  
    Chrome        Yes (version unknown)
```

So, I suggest you to use [**Brandon Aaron's jQuery plug-in**](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/bgpos.js) to have cross-browser support for background position.

If you examine the code; it first tests for `backgroundPositionX` property and see if it is supported by the browser. If not; it parses out the X and Y values from the `backgroundPosition` property.

*Note: Unlike suggested in the comments, CSS3 Transforms [**would not be helpful**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) to you since you need IE8 support.*